# Win32 Uderstanding semaphore

Tags: multithreading, winapi, semaphore

I'm new to Multithread in Win32. And I have an assignment with Semaphore. But I cannot understand this.

Assume that we have 20 tasks (each task is the same with other tasks). We use semaphore then there's 2 circumstances:

First, there should be have 20 childthreads in order that each thread will handle 1 task.

Or:

Second, there would be have n childthreads. When a thread finishs a task, it will handle another task?

The second problem I counter that I cannot find any samples for Semaphore in Win32(API) but Consonle that I found in MSDN.

Can you help me with the "**20 task**" and tell me the instruction of writing a Semaphore in WinAPI application (Where should I place CreateSemaphore() function ...)?

Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a thread for every task, which is a common approach, or you can use a "threadpool" where threads are reused. This is up to you. In both scenarios, you may or may not use a semaphore, the difference is only how you start the multiple threads.

Now, concerning your question where to place the CreateSemaphore() function, you should call that before starting any further threads. The reason is that these threads need to access the semaphore, but they can't do that if it doesn't exist yet. You could of course pass it to the other threads, but that again would give you the problem how to pass it safely without any race conditions, which is something that semaphores and other synchronization primitives are there to avoid. In other words, you would only complicate things by creating a chicken-and-egg problem.

Note that if this doesn't help you any further, you should perhaps provide more info. What are the goals? What have you done yourself so far? Any related questions here that you read but that didn't fully present answers to your problem?

Comment: Should I place CreateSemaphore() in WinMain or WM_CREATE?

Comment: It doesn't matter where, but when! If I were you, I would forget about windows for the time being and use a simple console application though to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are contrained to using semaphores only, you could use two semaphores to create an unbounded producer-consumer queue class that you could use to implement a thread pool.

You need a 'SimpleQueue' class for task objects.  I assume you either have one already, can easily build one or whatever.

In the ctor of your 'ProducerConsumerQueue' class, (or in main(), or in some factory function that returns a *ProducerConsumerQueue struct, whatever your language has),  create a SimpleClass and two semaphores.  A 'QueueCount' semaphore, initialized with a count of 0, and a 'QueueAccess' semaphore, initialized with a count of 1.

Add 'push(*task)' and ' *task pop()' methods/memberFunctions/methods to the ProducerConsumerQueue:

In 'push', first call 'WaitForSingleObject()' API on QueueAccess, then push the *task onto the SimpleQueue, then ReleaseSemaphore() API on QueueAccess.  This pushes the *task in a thread-safe manner.  Then ReleaseSemaphore() on QueueCount - this will signal any waiting threads.

In pop(), first call 'WaitForSingleObject()' API on QueueCount - this ensures that any calling consumer thread has to wait until there is a *task in the queue.  Then call 'WaitForSingleObject()' API on QueueAccess, then pop *task from the SimpleQueue, then ReleaseSemaphore() API on QueueAccess and return the task* - this this thread-safely dequeues the *task.

Once you have created your ProducerConsumerQueue, create some threads to run the tasks.  In CreateThread(), pass the same *ProducerConsumerQueue as the 'auxiliary' *void parameter.

In the thread function, cast the *void back to *ProducerConsumerQueue and then just loop around for ever, calling pop() and then running the returned task.

OK, your pool of threads is now ready to do stuff.  If you want to run 20 tasks, create them in a loop and push them onto the ProducerConsumerQueue.  The threads will then run them all.

You can create as many threads as you want to in the pool, (within reason).  As many threads as cores is reasonable for tasks that are CPU-intensive.  If the tasks make blocking calls, you may want to create many more threads for quickest overall throughput.

A useful enhancement is to check for 'null' in the thread function loop after each task is received and, if it is null, clean up an exit the thread, so terminating it.   This allows the threads to be easily terminated by queueing up nulls, making it easier to shutdown your thread pool, (should you need to), and also to control the number of threads in the pool at runtime.